# Is there a plugin to use permissions for Command Blocks in Minecraft rather than give op

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Am currently using LuckPerms and the autoop feature to allow a certain group to place and program Command Blocks. Ultimately we'd like to get rid of auto-op and all op permissions entirely, whilst retaining the ability for Command Blocks to be used by certain players via permissions. We are running Paper and Minecraft version 1.15.2. Is there a plugin and/or option to allow this?

Answer (score 2):

I looked for an answer online and I could unfortunately not find anything

However what may work as a partial workaround is reducing the op-permissions level in the settings file to 2 from 4 which disables server management commands (/ban, /whitelist, /kick, /stop, etc.) however these commands can still be ran in the server console. op permissions level 2 is the same permissions that command blocks run at so if you can trust players to add code to command blocks then you should be able to trust them with permission level 2. Any commands such as /give will be outputted into the server console/log so you can see if anyone breaks your trust.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue with what you are requesting is that if you give Command Block perms to to someone, they can then use a command block to run a /op command and give themselves op.

Command Blocks run commands at an op level - anyone who has access to command blocks has access to everything that an op does.

For this reason, Command Blocks can only be used by someone who is already op.